# Can I use my Bitcoins to buy household commodities just like ordinary money?

Tags: legal

Can I use my Bitcoins to buy household commodities just like ordinary money?  You see, I'm a newbie and have yet to learn the basics including all the facts about Bitcoins.  However,  I want to be ascertained as to whether my time and efforts in learning the trade will be rewarding in such a way that,  I'll be able to use whatever amount of Bitcoins I may earn someday to actually purchase things from the nearby store.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are relatively few shops that accept Bitcoin. If you want to know whether your local stores accept it, you will have to ask them. (Be prepared to be told "no" or more likely "I have no idea what you are talking about.")

Your title about "legal tender" is actually asking something different. "Legal tender" is a legal term, referring to a method of payment that must be accepted to settle a debt. As far as I know, Bitcoin is not legal tender in  any jurisdiction. However, people are still free to accept it if both parties agree (unless other local laws forbid it). In any case, legal tender is irrelevant to retail purchases, where no goods have already changed hands and no debt exists ahead of time. The seller can decide what forms of payment they do or don't want to accept.